# Laravel: Set mail subject from mail blade template

Tags: laravel, email

When using the Laravel 6 mail functionality, I would like to set the message subject in the email's blade template. This seems more natural to me than doing it in the Mail class itself, because whoever is maintaining the mail templates should also be able to customize the subject and use the template variables.

Example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
@component('mail::subject')
Sample Message to {{ $user }}
@endcomponent

@component('mail::message')
# Sample Message

This is a sample message
@endcomponent
```

How could this be done?

Comment: the template used is just the mail content, and so has nothing to do with the mail subject

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this as well. It took me a while to find a decent solution but here it is:

The mailable class:

```
class Mailing extends Mailable {

    use Queueable;
    use SerializesModels;

   ...

    public function build() {
        return $this
            ->markdown('emails.somemailing')
            ->with('setSubject', function($subject) {   // Use to be able to set the subject from within the markdown blade
                    $this->subject($subject);
                });
    }
}
```

Then in the markdown blade you can call the `setSubject` like this:

```
@php
$setSubject('Hooray, it works!');
@endphp

@component('mail::message')

...

@endcomponent
```

PS You can also set $this->subject directly as a closure:

```
->with('setSubject', Closure::fromCallable([$this, 'subject']));
```

Answer (score -1):

In APP - Mail

add this

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('emails.user')->subject('here subject');
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works but still we need to work with separate files for subject and body. I would like to change the subject in the blade template, so that people that cannot use PHP are still enabled to change the e-mail subjects